# Why can't I get the input value?

Tags: c

I cannot assign the input value to `bj`.
For example,when I input `756`,what I expect to get is `UTC at the same time: 2356`,however the computer gives me `UTC at the same time: 1600`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int bj;
    scanf("Input a BJT: %d", &bj);
    if(bj>=0&&bj<=2359&&bj%100<60)
    {
        if(bj<800)
            bj+=1600;
        else
            bj-=800;
        printf("UTC at the same time: %d",bj);
    }
    else
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: `scanf("Input a BJT: %d", &bj);` --> `printf("Input a BJT: ");scanf("%d", &bj);`

Comment: That's what you get when 1) don't initialize auto local variables 2) don;t check the return value of `scanf()`.

Comment: `if(bj>=0&&bj<=2359&&bj%100<60)`-> `if ((bj >= 0) && (bj <= 2359) && (bj % 100 < 60))` which is more readable.

Comment: are you avoid of spaces? put more of them to make the code readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scanf("Input a BJT: %d", &bj);
```

You've mixed up your `printf` and `scanf` functions somewhat. `scanf` specifies what the input should be so you don't want the output stuff in there as well as it'll end up expecting that in your input.

Split them out like this.

```
printf("Input a BJT:\n");
scanf("%d", &bj);
```

Comment: Nitpick: _"canf specifies what the input should be "_...actually it's the format string

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("Input a BJT: %d", &bj);
```

This line is messed up. Use it like:

```
printf("Input a BJT: ");
scanf("%d", &bj);
```

check this [link](http://www.sitesbay.com/cprogramming/c-printf-and-scanf)

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions:

1.

```
printf("Input a BJT:\n");
scanf("%d", &bj);
```

2.
When you input, you should input `Input a BJT:` before you input the value of `bj` .For example,I want `bj` equal `756`, so I input `Input a BJT: 756`.